# Golang render string as html in Revel

Tags: html, string, go, revel

I need to render string as html in `Revel`. How to do this?
I've tried:

```
func (c Pages) Show(url string) revel.Result {    
    bigDig := "<h1>Hello, dig!</h1>"

    return c.Render(bigDig)
}
```

and then in `view`:

```
{{template "header.html" .}}

{{.bigDig}}

{{template "footer.html" .}}
```

but it doesn't work. How to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what Revel is. Give a better explanation in what you're trying to achieve and people can help you better. Meanwhile, check out this example to learn how to handle forms in go. It's written for the app engine, but you'll get the idea. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/handlingforms

Comment: Rendering templates in Revel (http://revel.github.io/) is stated in this documentation: http://revel.github.io/tutorial/requestflow.html#hot-reload

And we have the same problem by which the variable passed from the controller can't be received by the templates/views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your var need to be in a template.HTML type.

Read http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/8L4eDkr5Q84.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your `{{.bigDig}}` into `{{raw .bigDig}}`